# How to Implement google translate API offline in my java appliaction

Tags: google-app-engine, google-translator-toolkit

I want know  information about the google translate API offline access. My application is blocking external service access so I can't use web service based translation  so I am planning to implement language translation based on the design offline access of google translate API.

will it possible to implement the translation without internet connection?